# C++ Generic code for deleting pointer value in Map and vector of pointers

Tags: c++

I have some generic code for deleting pointers within a vector or a value of a Map.

Is there a better way of doing this (without using shared_ptrs or any o fthe tr1 extensions )?

Also is the code correct?

Here is my code:

I have a namespace

```
#ifndef CONTAINERDELETE_H
#define CONTAINERDELETE_H

#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>


namspace ContainerDelete{

  template<class A, class B>
    struct DeleteMap
    {
      bool operator()( pair<A,B> &x) const
      {

        delete x.second;
        return true;
      }
    };

   template<class T>
    struct DeleteVector
    {
      bool operator()(T &x) const
        { 
          delete x;
          return true;
        }
    };
 }
 #endif
```

I would then use this namespace in some bit of code to delete a map or vector.

Test Map deletion.

```
#include "ContainerDelete.h"

using namespace std;

// Test function.
void TestMapDeletion()
{
   // Add 10 string to map.
   map<int,B*> testMap;
   for( int Idx = 0; Idx < 10; ++Idx )
   {
     testMap[Idx] = new B();
   }

   // Now delete the map in a single  line.
   for_each( testMap.begin(),
             testMap.end(),
             ContainerDelete::DeleteMap<int,B*>());
}
```

Test Vector Deletion

```
// Test Function.
void TestVectorDeletion()
{
  // Add 10 string to vector.
  vector<B*> testVector;
  for( int Index = 0; Index < 10; ++Index )
  {
    testVector.push_back( new B());
  }

  // Now delete the vector in a single  line.
  for_each( testVector.begin(),
            testVector.end(),
            ContainerDelete::DeleteVector<B*>());
}
```

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: shared_ptr is now standard (gcc 4.5 and VS2010 both support it), but if you don't want to use it until fully conforming compilers, you can use boost::shared_ptr which is almost the same. I would advise against implementing your own solution because there are lots of tricky corner-cases (unless you are doing it for educational purposes which is fine).

Comment: In C++11 the first attempt would always be to make the element type `std::unique_ptr<T>` and only look for alternatives if that doesn't fit your needs. Containers of raw pointers are always a bad idea because you don't know who *owns* the pointed-to objects. You might even have a mix of pointers to dynamic, static and automatic variables. How would the container be able to restrict the amount of damage you can do?

Comment: @KerrekSB The main problem that I have in my current code setup is the order in which I delete the pointers (as I pass by pointers by reference). I need to make sure I work from the last reference backwards so not to get dangling pointer? Would this be a good place to use shared_ptr

Comment: @MWright: I don't follow. How does the order matter? Do the pointed-to objects know of each other? That sounds like a maintenance nightmare...

Comment: @KerrekSB Sorry for not being clear. I use alot of pointers to pointers and pointers to vectors of pointers in my code. These objects also get passed to other classes by reference so I need to keep track of them. These pointer are regular pointers and not smart pointers. Would it be in my best interest to bite the built and recode using shared_ptr so my memory is handled appropriately?

Comment: @MWright: That's impossible to tell from here. If your code is working, then it might not be worth the effort. Run it through `valgrind` and see if you have zero errors. On the other hand, if your code is *incorrect* then I suppose you have to do something about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better would be if reduce the genericity as:

```
struct DeleteVector
{
    template<class T>  //use the template here!
    void operator()(T &x) const
    { 
      delete x;
    }
};
```

if you do so, then you could simply write this:

```
for_each(testVector.begin(),
         testVector.end(),
         ContainerDelete::DeleteVector());
```

No need to pass type argument when you use `DeleteVector`, for it is not a class template anymore!

Similarly, you can implement `DeleteMap` functor.

You should also rename `DeleteVector` to `DeleteT`, and `DeleteMap` to `DeletePairSecond`, as both of these can be used more generically. For example, `DeleteT` can be used even with `std::list`, or even with arrays.

Comment: this does look cleaner. Would I not need to have a return though in the overloaded operator () ?

Comment: But you declared it as returning a bool, should be void surely?

Comment: @BleepBloop: Oops. Yes. It was just a typo.

Comment: I thought I was going crazy! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code is ok. I can't imagine any other ways to delete the pointers. All you can do is to reduce explicit type specification like in upper question. I know one more uglier way to do it: functions deduce types of their template parameters. So you can write template function with the first argument - vector, second - ptr and then use std::bind of vector parameter to make this function accepting one parameter - ptr.
But functor is better and more flexible.

Comment: shared pointers can be very slow. If you don't copy the pointers intensively it's better to use them.