# C++ deleting pointer to a pointer when passing to a class

Tags: c++

I have some code for you guru's to check. I know this is probably ( definitely ) not the best way to go about deleting memory, but just let me know if it would potential be OK.

I know I should be using smart pointers, but I will do this in my next revision of the code.

Anyway here is my problem.

I have a class that is initiated each time in a loop. I pass this class pointer to a vectors of pointers to an object which also change in each iteration of the loop. e.x.

```
vector<A*>* ex_A
```

I then use these pointers to vectors in the class and Map them to each other by using

```
map< int, vector<B*>* >*  ex_map.
```

This new map can then be accessed through the class by one of the public member functions.

At the end of Loop I wish to delete the memory so that the next new Class can be instantiated without seg faulting.

Here is some example code of what I am doing:

Inside Class MainClass.cxx

```
MainClass::MainClass(vector<A*>* ex_A, vector<B*>* ex_B, vector<C*>* ex_C): m_ex_A(ex_A), m_ex_B(ex_B), m_ex_C(ex_C) {}

MainClass::MakeMap(){

 vector<A*>::iterator itr_A = m_ex_A->begin();
 for(; itr_A != m_ex_A->end(); itr_A++){

    //This member function returns a vector of B* that are dependent of A
    vector<B*>* dependent_B = changeVectorB((*itr_A));

    /Defined in Header File
    //map< int, vector<B*>* >* m_mapAofB;
    //Now get Map index of A with vector of B*
    (*m_mapAofB)[(*itr_A)->Inedx()] = dependent_B;

   }

}
```

I will want to delete m_mapAofB at some point so I would loop through each value of the map (which is a pointer to vector of pointers). I use something similar to this URL to achieve this.

[C++ Generic code for deleting pointer value in Map and vector of pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231026/c-generic-code-for-deleting-pointer-value-in-map-and-vector-of-pointers)

My main concern is when to delete this memory, as MainClass will be in a for loop. Should I delete the memory at the end of each iteration of the for loop. This would allow for the new instantiation of the MainClass??

e.x.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
     //This will also change each loop
     Vector<A*> ex1;
     Vector<B*> ex2;         
     Vector<C*> ex3;

     MainClass* ex_main = new MainClass(ex1,ex2,ex3);


     ///Do something....

     //Finished with class now delete pointers
     ex_main->DeleteMemory();

     delete ex_main;
}
```

Comment: Firstly, I will say that allocating and releasing memory in each iteration of a loop is going to be a massive performance hit. So in terms of your code, I would advise re-designing how your code works to allow the class to be reused in each iteration.

Comment: @Slade what would be a better solution? I am trying to manage my memory so I do not get any seq vaults due to memory leaks?

Comment: The type created by 'new' is known at compile-time, the lifetime of the 'MainClass' object is within the lifetime of ex1, ex2 and ex3. So you could instantiate MainClass as a local variable (MainClass ex_main(ex1, ex2, ex3). It would be much faster since the new/delete calls may be skipped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm confused on many levels by this and think it needs a redesign - but all that aside:

You state:

> as MainClass will be in a for loop. Should I delete the memory at the
>   end of each iteration of the for loop. This would allow for the new
>   instantiation of the MainClass??

So, why do you believe you need to dynamically allocate MainClass in the first place if you're planning on deleting the memory related to it at the end of each iteration? It can simply be a stack variable which is created at the top of the loop and destroyed each time it loops (or better yet, as described in Slade's comment, you can declare it above your loop so it isn't recreated every time - that would require you to have a public function to change it to mimic its constructor though).  Secondly, wrap your pointers in objects (I don't care if they're smart pointers for real, just wrap them) so when your vectors go out of scope your wrappers destructors will automatically delete the dynamically allocated contents.

Comment: So if I wrap my pointers in the class destructor instead of the DeleteMemory() function, the destructor will be called when I use delete?

Comment: Quite frankly, you should just switch to a TR1::shared_ptr, but since you're not up for that yet... Class A{}; class APtr { APtr(A* ptr): m_ptr(ptr) {} ~APtr() { delete ptr; } }; Would do you fine.  Do a std::vector APtrs instead (holding your pointers to A), and when the vector goes out of scope it will call APtr's destructor which will delete the pointer that it holds.

Comment: PS: You could make a class template that does that for all classes {A,B,C,...} assuming they all just take a pointer of type T store it, and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't allow for the new instantiation of MainClass, that's already allowed, it would free the memory which you should do. So yes, do it.